# sum linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to sum a variable inside of my linked list. I've got the following function but I'm getting errors on the line noted. I also think that I may not have finished the if statement correctly to return the summed value to the function.

```
int print_nodeprice1 (node *headptr, int num) {
int sum = 0;
node *first;
first = *headptr;    // getting errors that I can't assign this
while (first != NULL) {
    first = first -> next_ptr;
    if (num == first -> price1)
        return sum;
    else {
        printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Heh. No one knows which one to upvote.

Comment: Wheel of morality turn turn turn ... (Animaniacs reference. Get off my lawn)

Answer (score 1):

```
first = headptr;
```

this will work..since both are of type (node *)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues:

1. Assign first = headptr, instead of *headptr
2. Do your num check at the top of the loop, before setting first =
   first->next
3. You aren't actually summing anything. Did you mean to increment your
   sum variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
first = *headptr;    // getting errors that I can't assign this
```

Correct - you're trying to assign the value (dereference) to a pointer.

```
first = headptr;
```

Beyond that ... It's unclear what you mean about "sum a variable inside of my linked list". Your code returns `0` when it finds a `price1` that equals the `num` you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

```
int print_nodeprice1 (node *headptr, int num) {
node *first;
first = *headptr;    // getting errors that I can't assign this
```

`first` is a pointer to `node`, `headptr` is also a pointer to `node`. Now you try to assign to `first` the result of derreferencing `headptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `*`. It should be just:

```
first = headptr;
```

`first` and `headptr` are of type `node*`. The `*` operator dereferences them so `*headptr` is of type `node`, not `node*`.

Answer (score 0):

`first` is a pointer to `node`.  `headptr` is a pointer to `node`.  `*headptr` is a node.  You cannot assign a `node` to a pointer to `node`.